# button action does not work after rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have a relative layout with some button on it and I have created a rotation animation to rotate it

but when I rotate it the action of button does not work correctly, the action of button still save the old position of button before rotation

could any one please help me fixing this

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/last20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/last20_selector" 
        android:onClick="last20OnClick"/>
```

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wheel);

    RelativeLayout layout =  (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.wheelLayout);

    RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0, 45,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);

    rotateAnim.setDuration(1000);
    rotateAnim.setRepeatCount(0);
    rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    layout.startAnimation(rotateAnim);
}

public void last20OnClick(View view) {
        System.out.println("last20OnClick");
    }
```

Comment: did u find any solution? Facing same issue.

Comment: No, I didn't found the solution, and I build my control using canvas and stop using absolute layout.

Answer (score 0):

Where in your code do you set the `OnClickListener`?
Try putting the listener in you `onCreate` method:

```
findViewById(R.id.last20).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public abstract void onClick (View v) {
        last20OnClick(v);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: `However, instead of applying an OnClickListener to the button in your activity, you can assign a method to your button in the XML layout, using the android:onClick attribute. ` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: Yes I have set it in the XML file android:onClick

Answer (score 0):

Try to set attributes:

```
android:fillAfter="false"
android:fillBefore="false"
```

or in java:

```
rotateAnim.setFillAfter(false);
rotateAnim.setFillBefore(false);
```

as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065505/button-click-event-not-firing-in-second-view-of-a-viewflipper/8077702#comment11217123_8077702). It helped me.
Aslo, to preserve your animation rotate from -45 to 0 degrees.

Comment: No I can't do that because I need to keep the rotation

Comment: RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(-45, 0, ...); and you got same rotation.